# Error when trying to up apache spark master

Tags: apache-spark

When im trying to deploy at Windows this error comes. Im using apache-spark 2.0.

Command: `./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master`

Error: `./bin/spark-class: line 84: [: too many arguments`

Its the same error reported [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-issues/201607.mbox/%3CJIRA.12990046.1468659424000.49488.1468660161372@Atlassian.JIRA%3E)

Answer (score 1):

The command is wrong, i forgot the ".cmd". The right command is:

```
./bin/spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```